# script.js upload on site

Tags: jquery, html

I have finished  my project in code academy. Now I try upload my site. I save each file to folder as index.html, style.css and script.js, [image]
but when I open index.html it looks like script.js not work. Site don't have interactions.

Code:

```
<head>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="stylesheet.css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js">      
   </script>
   <title>Result</title>
</head>
```

and I thing that should works. 
I upload file from free server but still dont work.
http://www.battleship-dariusz-plichta.cba.pl/
what I should change?

Comment: i don't see `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>` in your live HTML code

Comment: +1 for a very cute project. Well done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include your jQuery code after including jQuery before jQueryUI:

```
<head>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="stylesheet.css"/>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
   <title>Result</title>
</head>
```

At the moment you do not appear to be including jQUery at all (just jQueryUI, *which is an addition to jQuery*).

If you display your website in Chrome's F12 debugger you will see:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined script.js:696
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.min.js:5
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: @user3387288: Please publish your changes to your website as it still does not have jQuery. Can't spot the other errors until you sort out that one first.

Comment: OK, thanks all. My project is finished :) http://www.battleship-dariusz-plichta.cba.pl/. I just graduated from codecademy so I'm very proud of this project :)